# C# Rider IDE can't create a new project

Tags: c#, .net, linux, msbuild, rider

I've installed Rider IDE on my Arch machine using flatpak, I face an error while creating new projects `Unable to load project and obtain project information from MsBuild`.

The error message says: Probably this project is incompatible with the current MsBuild.
MsBuild error details: Protocol connection was interrupted because the process has exited.

Anyone knows why it happens, and how can I fix the issue?

> I have .NET6 installed and everything (including build process) works on VSCode.

I've tried cloning MsBuild from the GitHub repo and building it locally, but that doesn't help either.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to change settings in the page which is specified on the image?

Comment: @xtmq Yes, I have, I installed MsBuild manually and updated the settings, but that didn't help.

Comment: Then probably this msbuild can not be executed for some reason. Try to read logs yourself or create an issue in JB public issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=RIDER

Comment: Also try to build some project from command line with your msbuild

Comment: Building projects from command line works perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

After all, I tried all the solutions found on the internet and realized it was an issue with the Flatpak package.

I believe the maintainer forgot to put some required files in the package, or this might be a *Permission* related issue!

My suggestions to all the other user who might come to this once in the future are:

1. Learn Flatpak fully, so you be able to track what's not working and why!
2. If you're on an Arch machine, it might be a better idea to search in the AUR first.